# Ubuntu 18.04 with ZFS on root, update to ZFS on linux 0.8 rc1

Tags: 18.04, encryption, compiling, zfs

04 test system, with ZFS on root (system disk) with LUKES encryption.

I'd like to update ZFS to version 0.8 RC1 that was just recently released, to test out the ZFS native encryption.

What do I have to think about to preserve the system and how should i proceed?

I guess it could lead to problems replacing ZFS installed by the package manager as I use ZFS for the file system?

If I compile and install ZFS 0.8 will it replace previously installed ZFS version.

Maybe beginner questions, but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Not a complete answer, so a couple of comments:

1) Get a VM up and running and play around with it there.

2) This is a great resource for ZFS root: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS

hope some of this is helpful.